# Currently MultibodyPlant does not handle joint limits for continuous models

Tags: robotics, drake

When I try to load a URDF file in drake I get the following error in relation to the joint limits:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>     what():  Currently MultibodyPlant does not handle joint limits for continuous models. However a limit was specified for joint ``haa_joint`."

Is there anything that can be done to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to consider this as a continuous-time model?  Joint limits are handled naturally in the time-stepping models.  It will work if you set time_step>0 in the MultibodyPlant constructor:

https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a042f9f9407c26eceeec309377eadcfa2